# ToggleSwitch - how to enable text?

Tags: windows-phone-7, toggle

I am using two toggleSwitches as below from the WP7 control toolkit.  Based on the first toggle, the second toggle switch should be enabled or disabled.  The disable of the second toggle switch works fine but when the enable is performed, the text foreground is never changed. Please help me figure out why this is happening.

```
<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Header="twitter" Margin="10,15,0,0" Name="toggleTwitter" Checked="toggleTwitter_Checked" Unchecked="toggleTwitter_Unchecked">
        <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
        <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Status: " FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
                        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
    </toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
    <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Header="" Margin="10,100,0,-35" Name="toggleTwitterAutoPublish" Checked="toggleTwitterAutoPublish_Checked" Unchecked="toggleTwitterAutoPublish_Unchecked">
        <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Auto Publish: " FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Margin="0,-15,0,0" />
                        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Content="{Binding}" IsEnabled="{Binding}" Margin="0,-15,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
    </toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
</Grid>


public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    bool isConnected = false;
    bool isAutoPublish = false;

    public const string SIGNED_IN_MESSAGE = "Signed In";
    public const string SIGNED_OUT_MESSAGE = "Signed Out";
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        toggleTwitter.IsChecked = isConnected;

        AlterTwitterControlsDisplay();

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }


    #region Twitter

    private void AlterTwitterControlsDisplay()
    {
        if (toggleTwitter.IsChecked.Value)
        {
            toggleTwitter.Content = SIGNED_IN_MESSAGE;
            toggleTwitterAutoPublish.IsEnabled = true;
            toggleTwitterAutoPublish.IsChecked = isAutoPublish;
        }
        else
        {
            toggleTwitter.Content = SIGNED_OUT_MESSAGE;
            toggleTwitterAutoPublish.IsEnabled = false;
            toggleTwitterAutoPublish.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }

    private void toggleTwitter_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isConnected = true;
        AlterTwitterControlsDisplay();
    }

    private void toggleTwitter_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isConnected = false;
        AlterTwitterControlsDisplay();
    }

    private void toggleTwitterAutoPublish_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isAutoPublish = true;
    }

    private void toggleTwitterAutoPublish_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isAutoPublish = false;
    }

    #endregion Twitter
}
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. i'd love to know the solution

Comment: I'm not clear what the issue is. The Foreground color is changing for me, with this code, when the second toggleswitch is enabled or disabled.

Comment: Agree with Matt. Foreground is gray while Status: Signed Out and white otherwise (actual for both Auto Publish On/Off). Is it not expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

On doing

```
toggleTwitterAutoPublish.IsChecked = false;
```

(in AlterTwitterControlsDisplay function's else part), the `toggleTwitterAutoPublish_Unchecked` is triggered which sets `isAutoPublish = false`

hence next time when you try to do

```
toggleTwitterAutoPublish.IsChecked = isAutoPublish;
```

here `isAutoPublish` is `false` hence you may not get the desired result.

That is what I have understood from your question. If this was not the problem please explain it clearly. Hope this helps